# Analog Vref for ADC on STM's Blue-Pill

Tags: adc, stm32f103c8t6

I am piecing together my own ADC example for STM's blue-pill module by reading the reference manual (btw I an inexperienced in embedded development).

The code outline so far is:

```
void do_adc(void)
{
    unsigned int ra;
    ra=GET32(ADC_CR2);

    ra|=1;   // ADON
    PUT32(ADC_CR2, ra);

    // wait for EOC flag
    while ((GET32(ADC_SR) & 0x02) == 1)
    {
        led_blink();
    }

    ra = GET16(ADC_DR);

    PUT32(USART1_DR,ra);
    sleep();

    PUT32(USART1_DR,'\r');
    sleep();
    PUT32(USART1_DR,'\n');
    sleep();
}

int notmain(void)
{

    init_led_adc_and_uart();
    disable_adc();
    calibrate_adc();
    enable_adc();
    while (1)
    {
        led_blink();
        do_adc();
    }
}
```

I have written code for each of those functions which most probably is not correct, but that's not the question at the moment.  I am still wondering where the Vref pin on the blue-pill; based on [this diagram](http://wiki.stm32duino.com/images/a/ae/Bluepillpinout.gif), is?

If my understanding is correct, then I would connect a temperature sensor to physical pin 10 (aka ADC channel 0), ensure that sensor has a voltage of ~3.3v.  Then for reference, connect the same input somewhere on the blue-pill so it can do the conversion.

However based on the diagram I linked, I am not sure where the analog referene is?

Btw: I flashed my code onto the chip and the led continuously blinks, so the code is **probably** fine, but I need to workout the connections!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't one in a 48 pin package, it's too small to have extra functions like that. Even the 64 pin doesn't have one, only when you get to 100 do they include the ref pins. 
[image]

They do have an internal reference, you'll have to configure it.

[image]
Sources: https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/cd00161566.pdf

Comment: What would happen if I simply start a conversion without configuring this? I just tried that and the output in uart is an empty string.

Comment: How can it be configured, to change the adc voltage reference value?